# Importing a module works in IDE but doesn't work in windows command line (edited)

Tags: python, import, command-line, module, pythonpath

I am new to Python so this may be a stupid question, sorry in advance if it is so!

The paths Python searches for modules using Spyder 4.1.4.:

```
[.., 'D:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages', ..]
```

The paths Python searches for when used via command line in windows:

```
[.., 'D:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages', ..]
```

Thus, both include path to

```
'D:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages'
```

where I store my cv2 module installed. Yet, Spyder can `import cv2` and to my surprise cmd cannot `import cv2` with an error `No module named 'cv2'`. What am I missing please? Can anyone verify if it works for him in command line please? (I changed/edited the question again to cut unneccessary long talk, though the essence stayed the same, in hope someone could answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. If you have a similar problem, you can check if your case is similar to mine and follow the steps.

I use Spyder and everything works fine. However my goal is to use Python via cmd. This could not be done because Python via cmd could not find my modules.

What I did: After typing `python` in cmd, Python worked and output its version by default. However, I noticed the version was *different* than version running in Spyder - I had two Python installations (one of which I didn't know about). I found the installation cmd uses by `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)`. I uninstalled that Python installation.

Now, typing `python` in cmd does not do anything, it is an unknown command. Then I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) to add my Python installation to Path (using Windows) by:

> `My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >`

in System variables, I found "Path", clicked Edit, New, then input my Python installation path `D:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3` as well as `D:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3\Scripts` and `D:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3\Library\bin`. This solved it for me.